# Статический метод и удаление инициализации класса

Tags: java, инициализация

Есть задание:

Объявите метод convertGrades() класса ReportCard как статический и удалите строку инициализации класса из метода main()

```
package Example;
public class ReportCard {

    public static char convertGrades (int testResult) {
        char grade;
        if (testResult >= 90) {
            grade = 'A';
        } else if (testResult >= 80 && testResult < 90) {
            grade = 'B';
        } else if (testResult >= 70 && testResult < 80) {
            grade = 'C';
        } else {
            grade = 'D';
        }
        return grade;
    }
    
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        ReportCard rc = new ReportCard();
        char yourGrade = rc.convertGrades(88);
        
        System.out.println("Ваша первая оценка " +yourGrade);
        yourGrade = rc.convertGrades(79);
        System.out.println("Ваша вторая оценка " +yourGrade);
    }
```

}

Метод convertGrades статическим объявил, но не пойму, где строка инициализации класса в методе main? Подскажите, спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Строкой инициализации в данном случае является строка

```
ReportCard rc = new ReportCard();
```

Пока ваш метод convertGrades  не был статическим вы не могли к нему обратиться из статического метода main , вам приходилось сначала создавать экземпляр класса ReportCard, а уже потом у переменной ReportCard rc вызывать нужный метод convertGrades.
В итоге код будет выглядеть так:

```
public class ReportCard {

    public static char convertGrades(int testResult) {
        char grade;
        if (testResult >= 90) {
            grade = 'A';
        } else if (testResult >= 80 && testResult < 90) {
            grade = 'B';
        } else if (testResult >= 70 && testResult < 80) {
            grade = 'C';
        } else {
            grade = 'D';
        }
        return grade;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char yourGrade = convertGrades(88);
        System.out.println("Ваша первая оценка " + yourGrade);
        yourGrade = convertGrades(79);
        System.out.println("Ваша вторая оценка " + yourGrade);
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!